# Toggle buttons and select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#BUTTON_1').on('click', function() {

    });
});
</script>
```

...

```
<td>
    <select id="selectBox" name="selectBox">
    <option value="R01"> REQUESTED </option> 
    <option value="R02"> NOT FINISHED </option> 
    <option value="R03"> FINISHED </option> 
</td>
```

```
<td>
<a href="#"  class="btnA" id= "BUTTON_1" value="N">UNCHECKED</a> 
<a href="#"  class="btnA" id= "BUTTON_2" value="N">UNCHECKED</a> 
<a href="#"  class="btnA" id= "BUTTON_3" value="N">UNCHECKED</a> 
</td>
```

...

```
<div>
<a id="fnModEncProc" class="btnB"><strong>SAVE YOUR WORK</strong></a>
</div>
```

So when I first open the page, I have a select box, 3 buttons and SAVE button.

The select box has 3 options (Default is **REQUESTED**)

1. When I click on each "UNCHECKED" button, I want it to toggle to "CHEKCED". (Same for BUTTON _2,3)
2. When only one or two the buttons have been **CHECKED** -> then select **FINISHED** in select box -> then click SAVE YOUR WORK

Then alert box should pop-up with **"All three buttons must be clicked in order to be FINISHED"** text.

**++** In short, when one or two are CHECKED, the select box option should be selected as **NOT FINISHED** when click on save button.

But when all are CHECK, then select box option should be selected as **FINISHED** when click on save button.

Can anyone help me coding this?

Comment: Do you really have these `td`s floating around in the html, without tr, table etc..? select missing its closing tag?

Comment: Oh I just omitted other parts to make it look simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Cmxk8/)</kbd>

```
$('.btnA').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var txt = $(this).text();
    txt = (txt == 'UNCHECKED') ? 'CHECKED' : 'UNCHECKED'; //toggle text
    $(this).text(txt);
});
$('#selectBox').change(function () {
    if (this.value === 'R03') {
        var len = $('.btnA').filter(function () {
            return $(this).text() === 'CHECKED'
        }).length; //get length of button with text CHECKED
        if (len !== 3) {
            $(this).val('R01'); //set value first to drop-down list
            alert('All three buttons must be clicked in order to be FINISHED');
        }
    }
});
$('#fnModEncProc').click(function () {
    $('#selectBox').change();
    var len = $('.btnA').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() === 'CHECKED'
    }).length; //get length of button with text CHECKED
    if (len === 3) $('#selectBox').val('R03'); //if length = 3 select FINISHED in drop-down list
});
```

---

<kbd>[**Updated fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Cmxk8/1)</kbd>

```
$('.btnA').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var txt = $(this).text(),
        val;
    if (txt === 'UNCHECKED') {
        txt = 'CHECKED';
        val = 'Y';

    } else {
        txt = 'UNCHECKED';
        val = 'N';
    }
    $(this).text(txt).prop('value', val); //set value to val
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But I got one last question.The default value for each button is 'N'. But if I want to give them 'Y' when each button is toggled, can you help me with this as well? I would appreciate it so much

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btnA').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('checked').text('Checked');
    var num_checks = $('.btnA.checked').length;
    $('#selectBox').val(num_checks < 3 ? 'R02' : 'R03');
});

$('#fnModEncProc').click(function () {
    if ($('.btnA.checked').length < 3) {
        alert('Must have 3 checked');
    }else{
        /* run save code*/
    }
})
```

Not entirely clear if user should be able to `uncheck`.Is not built into this version

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/698H5/3/)**</kbd>